# How can I also include normal content in an embedded message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

How do I also include normal content in an embedded message, just like the following image?

[image]

For instance, this is a normal embedded message.

```python
embed = discord.Embed(title="example", description="embed content")
await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to add content to a message as well as an Embed by specifying the content in the `reply()` parameters.

```py
from discord import Embed

content = "content"
embed = Embed(title="example", description="embed content")
await ctx.reply(content=content, embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use keyword argument [`content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=reply#discord.ext.commands.Context.reply) like this:

```py
    content = "text content"
    embed = discord.Embed(title="example", description="embed content")
    await ctx.reply(content=content, embed=embed)
```

Comment: Is "content" intended to be literal in the first sentence? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72439481/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).